# Use JSTL <sql:setDataSource> and <sql:query> in jsp page is secure

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, jstl

It is always recommended not to use Java code in a jsp page, so I use servlet (which contains Java code with SQL statements) and dispatch it to jsp page where I used JSTL cout tag, foreach tag to display.

But JSTL do provide `<sql:setDataSource>` and `<sql:query>` to do SQLrelated operations and display output.

What is the difference between writing SQL queries in servlet code and using jstl sql tags?

And is it secure to use JSTL sql tags in jsp page?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: None. A JSP image is still a servlet, so from the point of view of security there is zero difference. Some people have aesthetic or engineering objections to SQL in JSP pages. That's a different issue. Personally think Occam's Razor should be used a little more in computing.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is zero difference or not. For example, when using Scriptlets <% %> if you connect to the database without using try...catch, a connection error like the db server being inaccessible will expose the offending line of code and thus the connectionstring to the user if showing errors is turned on in the container. Whether JSTL will do the same or not, I don't know. Give your connectionstring bogus credentials and you'll find out.

Comment: @developerwjk A servlet can do that too. Poorly written code is always an issue.

Comment: @EJP, I guess if you didn't put a try..catch in your servlet. But its more likely you would do that in a servlet than JSP since the compiler will require you to unless you add the proper Exception type to the throws list to get around it.